# Mesosphere Installation in VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualbox, mesosphere

Can somebody please help me? I configure three masters following the [guide of digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04) and I'm trying to access the Mesos and Marathon interface using my host only adapter address, but it just says the site cant be reached and refused to connect

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking your question. First of all, the document you are referencing from Digital Ocean is from 2014 and while DC/OS *can* run on Ubuntu it is not a supported operating system for this product. There are also concerning suggestions in this article that I would avoid (such as only have a 2 Mesos Master quorum which it looks like you already noticed). Lastly, the company itself is called Mesosphere and the product is called DC/OS :)

With all that out of the way, since 2014 much has changed in DC/OS and the Digital Ocean document is obsolete. You no longer have to manually configure Zookeeper, cluster quorum size, Marathon, Mesos, edit host files on agents, or any of the other items this document references for a production cluster. All of that is taken care of in a YAML configuration file called   `config.yaml` if you attempt an "advanced" install.

You should have more success with connecting to the UIs (DC/OS, Marathon, and Mesos) by attempting an installation method that is up-to-date, on a tested and supported OS, and using the latest versions of DC/OS provided by Mesosphere. This will remove the difficulties you are seeing from the obsolete documentation.

https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/installing/oss/
https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/installing/oss/custom/system-requirements/
https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/installing/oss/custom/configuration/configuration-parameters/
https://docs.mesosphere.com/version-policy/

Hope this helps and you see success with DC/OS!

***Edit, if you want to avoid DC/OS, use the Mesos advanced course https://open.mesosphere.com/advanced-course/